# Bytes not the same when converting from bytes to string to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I have the following problem. When I read the bytes of an file via
`with open(r'file-path', 'rb') as file: data = file.read()` and write this byte object "data" into in other file using 'wb'. The out coming file is fine and there are no problems. But when I first convert the byte object "data" into a string `data_str = str(data)` and than convert it back using `new_data = data_str.encode()` "new_data" looks exactly the same as "data", but if I write "new_data" into a file the file isn´t working. Or as in my case not recognized as being an mp3 file, even though the bytes are the same on the first look.

I know it seems useless to convert the bytes into a string and than back into bytes, but in my case I really have to do that.

Comment: Try printing `data_str`. You'll see that it has literal `b'...'` around it. That's not the same as the original data. `str(data)` is returning the printed representation of the byte string, not a string containing the bytes themselves.

Comment: As you describe, `data != new_data`.  `str()` is NOT the way to convert bytes to strings.   Why do you think you need convert to a string?  Bytes strings are for binary data.  Unicode strings are for text.  If you need the binary data as text, you may need a binary to text converter (uuencode, base64, hexdump).  This is an XY problem.  Describe why you need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_str.encode()` expects `data_str` to be the result of `data.decode()`.

`str(data)` doesn't return a decoded byte string, it returns the printed representation of the byte string, what you would type as a literal in a program. If you want to convert that back to a byte string, use `ast.literal_eval()`.

```
import ast

with open(r'file-path', 'rb') as file: 
    data = file.read()
    str_data = str(data)
    new_data = ast.literal_eval(str_data)
    print(new_data == data)
```